# How can i make containers to four square grid? Gridview wasn't the exact solution

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I just started to Flutter, so I don't know specific things. Firstly, I want to show you an example about what I need to do;

---

---

[image]

---

---

First i tried Column and Row widgets but i couldn't place them as i need to. They are staying in the same way only, full colum or full row. I need to place two containers below and two containers above as you seen in the picture above.

Then I tried GridView.counter() about it, kinda works but i couldn't centered them and can't resize the containers in it. And also i don't know how to make them pressable (i know about containers)

Okay, this is my problem. If someone can help me, i really appreciate it. Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using wrap widget is GridView or GridView.builder is not a better option for you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Title will be here"),
            Wrap(
              spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent containers
              runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between horizontal line of containers
              children: List.generate(4,
                (index)=> Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black, 
                      width: 2.0
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy i'll try this!

Answer (score -1):

The following code will be one way of doing it.

```
class Extra extends StatelessWidget {
  const Extra({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SizedBox(
        height: 400,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Text("ITEM 1"),
              Text("ITEM 2"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Text("ITEM 3"),
            Text("ITEM 4"),
          ],
        ),
       )
     ]),
   )),
  );
 }
}
```

I am using a text widget here but you can render other widgets. Just know that column/row can cause overflow error. Provide width and height to their parents to prevent that. Also, using expaneded can help widgets to occupy available space. I am also using sizedbox but Container can replace it.